# Joomla! Extension Manager: Manage won't load

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

99% of the time when I try to load the Manage section of Extension manager, Joomla dies, giving me this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\vanillajoomla\libraries\joomla\string\string.php on line 399
```

Here's the line that's causing it (it's in a routine that compares string with locale considered):

```
if (!$locale = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $locale))
```

I've tried reinstalling several times, no dice.  This is locally installed under Windows 7 with XAMPP for testing a module I'm developing.  Googling the error reveals nothing, same for "php locale timeout."

Does anyone know what causes this, and how I can repair it?

Comment: usually this happens online when a page takes too long to load. I have never seen this on a localhost before. Try installing this to run your Joomla site offline. works like a charm. http://www.wampserver.com/

Comment: What does WAMP offer that XAMPP does not?

Comment: I haven't looked into the differences but I have never had this problem on wamp. Just out of curiosity, have you installed a lot of modules on your local server? Maybe try installing a fresh copy of joomla on a subdomain and seeing if you still get the same error.

Comment: No, the only modules I've installed were my own (HelloWorld and a basic calculator).

Comment: hmm very odd then. Re-install Joomla (latest version if you havent already got it) and see if you get the same error

Comment: I've figured SOMETHING out, see my answer below.

Comment: glad you got it fixed. sorry I wasn't much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my hack around it.  The problem seems to be with my module, but I can't figure out how or why.  Joomla seems to die when attempting to find the locale for my module.  Since the function helps sort strings by locale, I just added `return strcmp($str1, $str2);` at the beginning of the function.  It loses the locale functionality, but works now.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem, for now I've just commented the line out and it seems to be about 20 times faster with no problems found ;)

```
//if (!$locale = setlocale(LC_COLLATE, $locale))
{
 $locale = $locale0;
}
```

Another problem with my joomla is it takes a long time to load just anything - front or backend and it's from fresh installation (!joomla 2.5). It's some wrong setting with either Apache or PHP or MySQL, just can't figure out what's wrong exactly. Every other site on my localhost works sweet except for joomla.

Comment: Since Joomla is dynamic, the site will load a lot slower than other sites.  Don't forget to vote up the question and answer if they helped!

Answer (score 1):

okey it is probably caused by some plugin or module.. but what is the worst, it is not enough to turn them off.. I installed 3 plugin for voting (to test which is the best of them), one of them caused this type of crash the manager.. I turned off them but it didnt help.. I use an advice above, and commented line 399, than suddenly it worked.. I uninstalled all of them, then uncommented line 399 and everything was allright..hope this can help somebody..

Comment: Can you figure out *which* plugin/module it was?